# Javascript "Stop Typing" timer issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this question I have made a functional JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSCLC/

I am making a simple page where you either scan or type a UPC and it automatically adds to a table for display purposes. I scrapped up some code to start a timer that waits 3 seconds after typing is finished and then creates a new row in my table to display the typed in UPC and item information.

This code has a few problems though. (my questions)

A.) When you type in the UPC manually, the new row action happens multiple times (multiple rows get inserted for the same upc) But when you scan the UPC with a barcode scanner it only completes the action once. (which is correct)

B.) When you delete the information from the field (make the upc field blank) the new row action happens again but inserts a blank row.

C.) I tried to make the upc field blank after the row insert but that does not happen. I tried placing `upc='';` after the row inserts but that did not work. I defined `upc` like:

```
 var upc=document.getElementById("UPC").value;
```

(as you can see below and in the jsFiddle.)

So now for the code...

I just used a simple input for the upc field:

```
<input type="text" id="UPC" name="UPC" class="form-control scanning" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Scan or enter UPC here" />
```

and a simple table for the scanned items

```
<div class="scannedItems">
   <table class="table table-hover" id="ScannedItems">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>UPC</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>8754621160</td>
            <td>Example Product</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>5lbs</td>
            <td>$25.00</td>
            <td>
                <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="padding-right:15px"></span></a>
                <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

And then my Javascript

```
//setup before functions
var field = document.getElementById("UPC");
var typingTimer; //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 3000; //time in ms, 3 seconds

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#UPC').keyup(function () {
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#UPC').keydown(function () {
   clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
if (field.value.length == 0) {
   //do nothing
} else {
   function doneTyping() {
    var upc = document.getElementById("UPC").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML = upc;
    cell2.innerHTML = "Example Description";
    cell3.innerHTML = "$3.00";
    cell4.innerHTML = "7lbs";
    cell5.innerHTML = "$21.00";
    cell6.innerHTML = "<a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' style='padding-right:15px;'></span></a><span>&nbsp;</span><a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>";
    upc = '';
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/QAbGS/1/

1) You should always clear the old timer before resetting it, just overriding the variable doesn't clear it. The keydown event may not get there in time to clear it from before, so clearing it in keyup resolves this.

```
$('#UPC').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});
```

2) You were doing your npc length check outside of the function, this should be inside it!

```
function doneTyping () {
    if (field.value.length != 0) {
```

3) You were saving the value of the textbox to a variable named npc. You were then setting this variable to empty, not the textbox! You should do textbox.value = '' to reset this.

```
field.value = '';
```